# How to share data between react classes?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How can I share the data value that I have from the handleClick function inside the Module class to the InputSelect class, all the classes are in the same file?? I'm **not** using Redux.
I can't use props because there is not a relationship between these classes..
Should I nest all the classes??

Any suggestion??

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

const array = [ ];
class InputSelect extends React.Component {

  render() {
      return (
       <div> 
        { 'Put it here........' }
        </div>
       )
    }
}

class Module extends React.Component {

  handleClick(e) {
    console.log(e.currentTarget.textContent);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div
        onClick={this.handleClick}
      >
        {this.props.id}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

function App() {
  return (
      <div>
        <Menu availableModules={array} />
      </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: use react's context

Comment: or use HOC component. as old scool

Comment: There is a relationship between these classes; they need access (set or get) to the same state. You could introduce some state at the  App level and pass a function as a prop to Module that is called onClick that sets the state in App. That state is passed to InputSelect as prop. No need for.context.

Answer (score 0):

Correctly stated by @Federkun above, you should use React context.
Check the react docs [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html)